# perl: sprintf for element in list

Tags: perl, printf

I've been really confused about this, I'm trying to create a big matrix of numbers and I want to use `sprintf` with perl to have a nicer output. I'm trying to use `sprintf` like so

```
my $x = 0;
my $y = 0;
for ($x=1; $x<=$steps; $y++) { # loop through lines
for ($y=0; $y<=$distances; $y++) { 
my $format = sprintf ("%s",$matrix[$x][$y]);
```

but this is really doing my head in, as I am looping through all the values of $x and $y and getting their combinations. So I am not sure if I'm meant to use more formatting arguments like so

```
my $format = sprintf ("%s%s%s",$matrix[$x][$y]);
```

(of course this is giving me compilation errors as it's not right)

But when I only use one argument, I can't put spaces in between my columns :/ Can somebody explain what's happening? I really don't understand what I'm meant to do to get the formatting nice. I'm looking to just align the columns and have a couple of whitespaces between them. Thank you all so much.

Comment: Are you doing every element of the 2d matrix? Because that simplifies things. (Is `$distances` the number of elements in `$matrix[y]`?)

Comment: And if you're just formatting - does it have to be `sprintf` - because I'd be thinking using tab stops (`\t`)

Comment: Also - `for ($x=1; $x<=$steps; $y++) {` - should probably be `$x++`.

Comment: @Sobrique What about why `$x` is initialized to 0 and then immediately changed to 1? There's surely some sketchy stuff going on in just 5 lines of code. ;-)

Comment: @kouki: do you know whether these are ints or floats or mixed types?  This matters for nice formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
for my $row (@matrix) {
   my $format = join(' ', ('%5.2f') x @$row)."\n";
   printf($format, @$row);
}
```

If all rows have the same number of columns, you could calculate the format once.

```
if (@matrix) {
   my $format = join(' ', ('%5.2f') x @{$matrix[0]})."\n";
   for my $row (@matrix) {
      printf($format, @$row);
   }
}
```

If the size of the columns isn't unknown in advance, you'll need to need to perform the following in order:

1. Format the cells (if needed),
2. Find the length of the largest cell of each column, then
3. Print out the matrix with padding.

The following assumes every row of the matrix is the same length.

```
use List::Util qw( max );

if (@matrix) {
   for my $row (@matrix) {
      $_ = sprinf('%.2f', $_) for @$row;
   }

   my $num_cols = @{$matrix[0]};

   my @col_sizes = (0) x $num_cols;
   for my $row (@matrix) {
      $col_sizes[$x] = max(0, $col_sizes[$x], $row->[$x]);
   }

   my $format = join(' ', map { "%$_s" } @col_sizes)."\n";
   for my $row (@matrix) {
      printf($format, @$row);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is what I do, but note that it will silently convert int to float, and this may (or may not) be a problem.

Comment: @zdim, The OP didn't specify what format they wanted. I used `%5.2f` as an example. If another format is more appropriate, they should use that.

Comment: Right, clear and good.  My point is that if numbers have mixed ints and floats this way of printing hides that.    I sometimes have to print numbers for easy review and it turns out it is a little tricky because of that.  In fact I don't know of a way to do it simply, after years and years of banging at it.  (Have a lib that interrogates input, adjusts `%` etc, but that's horrible and off-topic here.)   [Don't know how to enter at-name??]

Comment: @zdim, If you have a random mix of ints and floats, you can't mechanically format them, so you wouldn't,

Comment: Because it may be critical to know whether a number came in as an integer or a float.  In scientific applications this may make or break things.  I may be scanning numbers for that reason alone.  (Or it may not matter, of course.)  But you have a point there, one just can't do it directly, period.

Comment: @zdim, It sometimes gets removed when it's redundant, e.g. when the person is the author of the post to which you are replying.

Comment: Ahhh!  Of course :).  Thank you.  I will remove these comments now.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Thank you!  I actually did look at that document and didn't see a specific way to do it (which I thought may be needed) or why/when it wouldn't work.  I guess I should've read the thing carefully ... I see, right on top of the accepted answer.  Sorry for wasting time and bandwidth (of all kinds).

Answer (score 0):

I would be thinking in terms of using `map`, as a way to display *every* element:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @matrix = ( [1,2,3,4],
               [5,6,7,8], 
               [9,10,11,12], );

 print join ("\n", map { join ( "\t", @$_ ) } @matrix );
```

This is formatting on tab-stops, rather than fixed width columns, and outputs:

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
```

If you particularly wanted `sprintf` though:

```
foreach my $row ( @matrix ) { 
   print map { sprintf("%5s", $_) } @$row,"\n";
}
```

(5 columns wide).

In each of these, I'm working on whole rows - that only really applies though, if I'm right about the assumptions I've made about which elements you're displaying.

At a very basic level - your code could work as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @matrix    = ( [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], 
                  [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], 
                  [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ], );

my $steps     = 2;
my $distances = 3;

for ( my $x = 1; $x <= $steps; $x++ ) {    # loop through lines
    for ( my $y = 0; $y <= $distances; $y++ ) {
        printf( "%5s", $matrix[$x][$y] );
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Although note - that will only work with equal numbers of columns. You could, however, do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @matrix    = ( [ 1, 2, ], 
                  [ 3, 4, 5,  ], 
                  [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ], );

my $steps     = 2;
my $distances = 3;

for ( my $x = 1; $x <= $steps; $x++ ) {    # loop through lines
    for ( my $y = 0; $y <= $distances; $y++ ) {
        printf( "%5s", $matrix[$x][$y] // '' );
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Which omits the first row (because you set `$x` to 1), and iterates up to 4 columns:

```
3    4    5     
6    7    8    9
```

This omits the extra values on the last line, and uses `//` to test if the cell is empty or not.

Comment: Nice, but will not line up decimal points and this may be a killer in some applications.  (I sometimes use formatted prints to spot check or look for things and it is critical that things are lined up.)

Comment: The OP specifically asked to be able to place spaces between the columns. Your (s)printf  solutions leave no spaces between the columns (or makes the first column larger than the others, depending on how you look at things).